# change environment variable on remote Windows machine

Tags: windows, environment-variables, psexec, setx

I'm trying to set an environment variable on a remote machine.

```
setx /s machine var value
```

doesn't work - it produces no output and doesn't do anything.

```
psexec \\machine setx var value
```

says it changed the value successfully. However when I go to the machine and open cmd, it doesn't show it. It does appear in the computer->properties->advanced->environment variables. Also, when I run

```
psexec \\machine cmd /c set
```

it is written correctly.

I wrote a program called RefreshEnvironment.exe that basically does the following:

```
    SendMessageTimeout(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0,
    (LPARAM) L"Environment", SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG,
    5000, &dwReturnValue);
```

If I call it on local machine, it fixes the problem - I open cmd after it and get the correct environment. However, it doesn't work remotely. Calling

```
psexec \\machine RefreshEnvironment.exe
```

returns "Access is denied". I can only run it with explicitly writing the user and password:

```
psexec \\machine -user domain\username -p password RefreshEnvironment.exe
```

Very strange since it is the same domain,username and password on both machines; and it doesn't work - didn't say anything, but I still can't see the environment on the local machine.

Any idea will be welcome.

Comment: You probably need to call SendMessageTimeout in the context of the logged-on user's session.  Unfortunately that's not easy to do with code; if you go this way, you might want to start by looking up the WTSQueryUserToken function (in which case you should use the -s option to psexec).  Alternately psexec with the -i option might work, but you'll need to find out which session the user is logged into first.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the "Remote Registry" service is running on the target computer when using the /s parameter. Could this be the cause of your issue? On Windows 7,  I receive a "ERROR: The specified operation could not be completed" if that service is not running on the remote computer.